# JBO-25014: Another user has changed the row with primary key oracle.jbo.Key[x]

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm working on a project "maintenance project" and it contents of sender and receiver,I'm using same table ,same EO and VO for process..
i have a problem when i update records this massage shown"Another User Have changed the Row with Primary Key"
im using oracle jdevolper 12c with DB 11g

Comment: i Changed Indicator attribute to all attributes it doesn't work! on P.Key attribute i have PK trigger for Squence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several posts that answer this - Start with the Oracle Support link:
https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Cloud/2502497_1.html

https://cedricleruth.com/how-to-fix-oracle-jbo-rowinconsistentexception-jbo-25014-another-user-have-changed-the-row-with-primary-key-in-adf/

https://www.jobinesh.com/2011/02/yet-another-reason-for-jbo-25014.html

https://tfathy.blogspot.com/2011/04/another-user-has-changed-row-with.html

Comment: i solved by check  Change Indicator and update when insert to the PK field